# Unable to debug remote Azure Website

Tags: debugging, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-web-app-service, remote-debugging

I am attempting to debug / walk through some code that is deployed on Microsoft Azure. I am able pass the credentials and attach my debugger successfully to w3wp.exe:

[image: Debugger attached]

From here, I am unable to get any breakpoints to hit because no symbols have been loaded. Error listed on the break point (hollow):

> "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded
>   for this document"

I have deployed my application to azure in **DEBUG** mode.

More info:

- Remote debugging is enabled on azure, set to VS 2015 (The version I
  am using)
- No changes have been made since deployment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what was going on - created a new website in Azure and I can connect to it fine now.